Calling Restlet from External Suitelet
I've been encountering some issues here and there with some externally available suitelets where certain issues occur that disappear when instead accessing the suitelet internally. For some of these issues, I was thinking a good workaround would be to offload the affected execution to a restlet. I'm working on the theory that the issues are based on whether or not a user is executing the code. My issue is that I've never been good with connecting to restlets, and what I've seen out there I believe is now outdated. I don't think they allow username/password authentication to restlets these days. Is there a good reference to use that highlights the best way to call a restlet from within a suitelet? I can't just directly use a restlet because the suitelet generates a web page for data entry, so I'm hoping this is feasible.
I'd like to link to a page that contains what they say to do, but it requires a NetSuite login to access. But I can detail out what it says, and where I have trouble.
So, they start by saying to determine the url and verb, which, yeah, ok, whatever, I already know that. Then they say to sort out the url parameters alphabetically with their values. Below I have a screen shot of their example.

At this point, I'm not sure how to generate the nonce value or the timestamp value. I had done this once before, but in C#, and I don't have the same libraries to utilize from within SuiteScript that I did using .NET. If there are external libraries that work well in SuiteScript, or methods available in the 2.0 API modules, that can generate those values, that would be great to know.
Moving on... It then says to concatenate the key/value pairs using an ampersand. Pretty much a standard url after the question mark. After that it says to url encode that string. Also not a problem. After that, they want a string something along the lines of HTTP_VERB%{url_encoded_base_url}&{url_encoded_parameter_string}. That's also nothing I'm concerned with putting together. However, this next part is also something I'm not sure how to accomplish.
This next step states to sign this result string using the consumer secret and token secret using an ampersand. I'm really not sure how that's supposed to be accomplished from within SuiteScript. After this, it wants that resulting value Base64 encoded, which is easy, and that value is to be url encoded. After that, I'm not sure how this value is supposed to be passed to the restlet for authentication. I assume it's to be set to a header, but I think I'm overlooking what it is.
-- EDIT --
I have managed to find some references I hadn't previously seen, and I built up some code to handle the process. So far, it results in this response:
error code: INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT
error message: Invalid login attempt.

This is my code so far:
const onRequest = (context) => {
    require(['N/crypto', 'N/encode', 'N/https', 'N/url'], (crypto, encode, https, url) => {
        const tokenId = "ABC123",
            tokenSecret = "DEF456",
            clientKey = "GHI789",
            clientSecret = "JKL012",
            guid = "MNO345";
        
        let restReqUrl = url.resolveScript({
                    scriptId : "customscript_restlet_1"
                ,   deploymentId : "customdeploy_restlet_1"
                ,   returnExternalUrl : true
            }),
            restReqBaseUrl = restReqUrl.substring(0, restReqUrl.indexOf("?")),
            restReqParams = QueryString(restReqUrl), // function that retrieves url params and returns JSON object
            nonceLength = 11,
            nonce = Math.floor(Math.pow(10, nonceLength - 1) + Math.random() * (9 * Math.pow(10, nonceLength - 1))),
            timeStamp = parseInt(((new Date().getTime()) / 1000).toString()),
            realm = "TSTDRV123456";
        
        let oauthPart1Arr = [
                    `deploy=${restReqParams.deploy}`
                ,   `oauth_consumer_key=${clientKey}`
                ,   `oauth_nonce=${nonce}`
                ,   `oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256`
                ,   `oauth_timestamp=${timeStamp}`
                ,   `oauth_token=${tokenId}`
                ,   `oauth_version=1.0`
                ,   `script=${restReqParams.script}`
            ],
            oauthPart1 = oauthPart1Arr.join("&"),
            oauthPart1UrlEnc = escapeURL(oauthPart1), // function that escapes special chars in a url
            oauthPart2Arr = [
                    "GET"
                ,   escapeURL(restReqBaseUrl)
                ,   oauthPart1UrlEnc
            ],
            oauthPart2 = oauthPart2Arr.join("&"),
            sKey = crypto.createSecretKey({
                    guid
                ,   encoding : encode.Encoding.UTF_8
            }),
            hmacSHA256 = crypto.createHmac({
                    algorithm : crypto.HashAlg.SHA256
                ,   key : sKey
            }),
            digestSHA256,
            base64Signature;
        
        hmacSHA256.update({
                input : oauthPart2
            ,   inputEncoding : encode.Encoding.UTF_8
        });
        
        digestSHA256 = hmacSHA256.digest({
                outputEncoding : encode.Encoding.HEX
        });
        
        base64Signature = encode.convert({
                string : digestSHA256
            ,   inputEncoding : encode.Encoding.HEX
            ,   outputEncoding : encode.Encoding.BASE_64
        });
        
        let oauthPart3Arr = [
                    `realm="${realm}"`
                ,   `oauth_consumer_key="${clientKey}"`
                ,   `oauth_token="${tokenId}"`
                ,   `oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256"`
                ,   `oauth_timestamp="${timeStamp}"`
                ,   `oauth_nonce="${nonce}"`
                ,   `oauth_version="1.0"`
                ,   `oauth_signature="${escapeURL(base64Signature)}"`
            ],
            oauthPart3 = oauthPart3Arr.join(","),
            oauthPart4 = `OAuth ${oauthPart3}`;
        
        let restReq = https.get({
                url : restReqUrl
            ,   headers : {
                        Authorization : oauthPart4
                }
        });

        context.response.write({ output : restReq.body });
    });
}

Best I can tell, everything is working correctly but I think I'm doing something wrong with the signature. For the GUID stored within NetSuite, I created the combined secret like this:
let tokenSecret = "DEF456",
    clientSecret = "JKL012",
    combined = `${clientSecret}&${tokenSecret}`;

I added it to the system and retrieved the GUID using this suitelet:
const onRequest = (context) => {
    if (context.request.method === "GET") {
        require(['N/ui/serverWidget'], (widget) => {
            let form = widget.createForm({
                    title : "Token GUID"
            });
            
            form.addSecretKeyField({
                    id : "combined_secret"
                ,   label : "Combined Secret"
                ,   restrictToScriptIds : ["customscript_suitelet_1","customscript_restlet_1"]
                ,   restrictToCurrentUser : false
            })
                .maxLength = 100;
            
            form.addSubmitButton({
                    label : "Submit"
            });
            
            context.response.writePage({ pageObject : form });
        });
    }
    else {
        let guid = context.request.parameters['combined_secret'];
        context.response.write({ output : `GUID: ${guid}` });
    }
}

I'm still missing a little something here since I keep getting a 403 error in response.
-- EDIT #2 --
I should also mention that the setup for the integration, role, and access token seems to be not the cause. I was able to successfully test using Postman with OAuth 1.0 to access the Restlet. When I compare the header generated by Postman with what is created from my Suitelet, they are very similar with notable differences due to them not having the same nonse and timestamp. I assume that I'm doing something wrong with the final signature.

You can investigate calling your RESTlet via the https.requestRestlet(options) operation. Note that your RESTlet will have to be deployed to the role that the Suitelet is running under.
If you are trying to POST to your external SUITELet you will likely not be able to do that without a cookie indicating a NetSuite session (either UI or SuiteCommerce).

That does seem to work, but it doesn't call it with any kind of user except for "-System-", which is what I'm trying to avoid. I want to have a user logged into the restlet to see if that makes a difference.

You cannot have a user logged in to a restlet.  You can call restlets from client scripts though which, if the user is logged in to Netsuite, will call the restlet as that user. It might be useful if you can provide overview of the parts of your system.

Yeah you can. That's kind of the whole point of passing in credentials to a restlet.
